# Is there a way to group_by a variable, str_detect in each group and store that result in a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to take a data frame, `group_by` a variable then assess each group to see if a separate variable contains a string in *any* of the rows in that group.

Using this information, I want to create a new column containing the result.

*i.e.* If at least one row in the group contains the string, the value in the new column *for each row in the group* should be `TRUE`.
If no rows in the group contain the string, the group's values in the new column should be `FALSE`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
    A=c('red','red','red','blue','blue','blue'),
    B=c('yes','no','no','no','no','no')
)
```

For example, trying to detect the string 'yes' in Column `B`, separately for the `red` and `blue` groups of Column `A`

```
df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    mutate(yes_in_group = ifelse(str_detect(B, 'yes'), TRUE, FALSE))
```

I would expect to see each value of `yes_in_group` to be `TRUE` for the `red` group and `FALSE` for `blue`, but `mutate` does not respect the groups.

```
expected <- tibble(A=c('red','red','red','blue','blue','blue'),
                   B=c('yes','no','no','no','no','no'),
                   yes_in_group=c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))

actual <- tibble(A=c('red','red','red','blue','blue','blue'),
                 B=c('yes','no','no','no','no','no'),
                 yes_in_group=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current use of `ifelse` doesn't do anything: you take the output of `str_detect()`, which is `TRUE`/`FALSE`, and convert it into `TRUE`/`FALSE`. To expand the result out to the entire group, you can use `any`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    mutate(yes_in_group = any(str_detect(B, 'yes')))
```